# Error: Class 'League\Flysystem\AwsS3v3\AwsS3Adapter' not found

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, file-upload, flysystem

laravel Framework is 7.9.2.

composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 ~1.0 
installed to use aws s3.

It runs on localhost, but when I put it on the aws server,

Error: Class 'League\Flysystem\AwsS3v3\AwsS3Adapter' not found  error appears.

However, when I checked with composer licenses,

It is identified as league/flysystem v1.0.67 MIT.

I don't know what the problem is.
If you have any difficulties like me, please help me.

Comment: how does your composer.json look and is flysystem-aws in your lock file?

Comment: try running `composer dump-autoload` and try again.

Comment: @mrhn composer.json has flysystem-aws-s3-v3.

Comment: @djunehor I've tried composer dump-autoload, but nothing has changed.

Comment: What triggers this error? Does it happen when you try to access a specific route or it occurs whenever you try to do anything - run a command, access a route etc?

Comment: @djunehor Errors that occur every time you save an image with S3.

Comment: @djunehor every time store function is run.

Comment: Does the lock have flysystem-aws-s3-v3 too?

Comment: @mrhn Yes, there is.

Comment: That means the class was not imported properly. Goto whichever file is handling the store function and import the AWS class properly

Answer (score 8):

This probably isn't going to help you, but I stumbled across this looking for a solution to the same error. It looks like the League S3 AWS V3 adapter had an upgrade and the version 2 branch doesn't use the same class names. I specified the version I wanted like this in `composer.json` and that seemed to sort it out:

```
    "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "1.0.29",
```

Comment: Thank you mate! This is the correct solution.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you should try run this command in terminal

```
composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 ^1.0
```

Comment: For those on Laravel 9, you'll need to upgrade to v3.0 instead.

composer require -W league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 "^3.0"

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem... it may not apply to you...

I still got the problem after

```
composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3
```

The reason being is since Oct2020 the class was renamed from

AwsS3Adapter to **AwsS3V3Adapter**

Comment: Got Error:
    - league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3[2.1.0, ..., 2.x-dev] require league/flysystem ^2.0.0 -> found league/flysystem[2.0.0-alpha.1, ..., 2.x-dev] but the package is fixed to 1.1.9 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - Root composer.json requires league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 ^2.1 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3[2.1.0, 2.x-dev].

Comment: If you are using a newer version of laravel, its one of the require dev options but not installed by default. You can see it in the suggestions: 
"suggest": { ..., "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "Required to use the Flysystem S3 driver (^3.0).", ...}

Answer (score 1):

It is due to the `composer.lock` file which has `league/flysystem-aws-s3-v2`.

something like :

`"league/flysystem-aws-s3-v2": "Allows you to use S3 storage with AWS SDK v2"` **( the problem)**

`"league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "Allows you to use S3 storage with AWS SDK v3",`

**Solution**

Simple run `composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3`

Comment: Got Error:
    - league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3[2.1.0, ..., 2.x-dev] require league/flysystem ^2.0.0 -> found league/flysystem[2.0.0-alpha.1, ..., 2.x-dev] but the package is fixed to 1.1.9 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - Root composer.json requires league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 ^2.1 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3[2.1.0, 2.x-dev].

Answer (score 1):

### Laravel 8

install with `--update-with-all-dependencies` flag

```
composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 "~1.0" --update-with-all-dependencies
```

Comment: how do we install in laravel 9? it says, laravel 9 is only compatible with league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3:3.0

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting same error when I have upgraded to lumen 10 from lumen 6
and version of flysystem and flysystem-aws-s3-v3

```
"league/flysystem": "3.10",
"league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^3.15",
```

to resolve this error I have to change code from

```
 $client = $storage->getAdapter()->getClient();
```

to this

```
$client = $storage->getClient();
```